# Resize a UITableView Header without autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, header

Is it possible to resize a `UITabeView` Header after the text is set to it? 
In my xib I got a TableView with a header with a height of 42 for 1 line of text. For 2 lines I need a height of 52 and for 3 I need 62.  The title is set dynamically to the header. But the `heightForHeaderInSection` func is called before the header text is set by the Lifecycle. So maybe lines 2 & 3 are not shown.

I wrote a method which tells me how many lines of text the header got but how to update the header? if i call `tableView.reloadData()` I end up in an infinity loop. And if I set var for every lineamoun
t I found the `heightForheaderInSection` is never called.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerCell) as! SectionHeader
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.sectionTitle

    linesOfHeader = cell.getNumberOfLines()


    return cell
  }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if(linesOfHeader == 1) { return 44}
        else if(linesOfHeader == 2) {return 52}
        else { return 62}
  }
```

Comment: Set up a property observer for `linesOfHeader` and call `tableView.reloadData()` from inside the `disSet` method of `linesOfHeader`. This way your `tableView` will only be redrawn exactly once each time `linesOfHeader` changes.

Comment: boundedrect method of string can help you get height and width of label from which you can pass height to header.

Comment: @DávidPásztor same loop. reloadData() calls viewForHeaderInSection where i set the lines of Header. So i will end up in a loop.

Comment: So don't set the `linesOfHeader` in `viewForHeaderInsection`, but set it when the number of lines can actually change.

Comment: its at this point. when i set the text the line change. so i have to set it there.

Answer (score 0):

a better solution to support dynamic header height is using "UITableViewAutomaticDimension" like this:

In viewDidLoad add these lines:

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 50
```

and remove the function heightForHeaderInSection

Then allow the label to extend to the required number of lines

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerCell) as! SectionHeader
       cell.titleLabel.text = self.sectionTitle
       cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3
     return cell
    }
```

if the header height overlap the cells height as well add these two lines to viewDidLoad

```
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40 // estimated cell height
```

Comment: The `numberOfLines` parameter should be set to 0, so `Autolayout` can figure out the necessary number of lines on its own. Also, keep in mind that for `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to work `Autolayout`  needs to used.